# Postgres time difference between time stamp in minutes

Tags: postgresql, datetime, lag

i need to calculate time difference between datetime rows. But i want to calculate them daily also i want to group them with id. How can i do this? my table is like this:[image]

Comment: Please share the expected results

Answer (score 1):

Th trouble comes in with the ambiguous term "difference in minuets from timestamp". When Postgres performs timestamp subtraction the result is an interval. But an interval consists of days, hours, minuets, and seconds. When you say difference in minuets do you mean to extract the minuets from the interval. Or do you mean total minutes represented by (24*60*days)+(60*hours)+(minuets), or something else? See the following examples:

```
with test_dates(d1,d2) as
     ( values ('2019-10-02 11:00:47'::timestamp, '2019-10-02 07:35:02'::timestamp)
            , ('2015_09-15 11:15:42'::timestamp, '2019-10-22 17:45:00'::timestamp)
     ) 
select greatest(d1,d2) - least(d1,d2) int_diff
     , extract('minutes' from greatest(d1,d2) - least(d1,d2)) min_diff 
     , 60* (extract('hours' from greatest(d1,d2) - least(d1,d2))) +
       extract('minutes' from greatest(d1,d2) - least(d1,d2)) diff_hr_min
     , (24*60)*(extract('days' from greatest(d1,d2) - least(d1,d2))) +
       60* (extract('hours' from greatest(d1,d2) - least(d1,d2))) +
       extract('minutes' from greatest(d1,d2) - least(d1,d2))  diff_daya_hr_min          
from test_dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT DATE_PART('minute', max(date) - min(date)) AS time_difference 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY DATE(date), id;
```

You can add `id` and `DATE(date)` to the `SELECT` to check if it's true result, like:

```sql
SELECT DATE(date), id, DATE_PART('minute', max(date) - min(date)) AS time_difference 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY DATE(date), id;
```

See [Postgresql extracting functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) and [Date/Time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) for more info.

Comment: This will result in only the minute *field*. If the difference is 2 hours and 10 minutes it will only return 10 minutes. Example: `select date_part('minute', '2h 10m'::interval);`.